# Joomla: Lot of queries make my site-performance bad after going to dead-link

Tags: mysql, sql, performance, joomla

since migration from my old joomla 1.5 site to 3.x last year, i have crazy performance problems: The time to first get is very high (> 1000 ms)
after hours and nights working and searching to find the reason, i find out that certain actions on my site produces lot of queries.

1. (Maybe) Bots called very often completely irrelevant pageviews on my site, that generates lot of queries
   For example:
   This is my impressum-link: http://www.hdsports.at/impressum/
   Bots called these link: /impressum/images/joomgallery/thumbnails/ballsport_4/faustball_47/bundesliga_2012-02_20120212_1204309660.jpg
   I have no menu-point under impressum. I dont no which bot (or anything) other called these links.

In my "/logs"-Folder i let producing sql-files from every pageview on my site (github.com/joomla/joomla-cms/pull/6202)
so i looked on the "HDsports.at_impressum108.sql"-file after i called these dead link.

And what i see on the sql-file.
More then 5000 of these queries:
SELECT m.tag_id,t.* FROM ngie_contentitem_tag_map AS m  INNER JOIN ngie_tags AS t  ON m.tag_id = t.id WHERE m.type_alias = 'com_content.article' AND m.content_item_id = 8662 AND t.published = 1 AND t.access IN (1,1,5);

there is for every of my article-id's one query.

one row before the first of these queries, there is these query:

SELECT a.id, a.title, a.alias, a.introtext, a.fulltext, a.checked_out, a.checked_out_time, a.catid, a.created, a.created_by, a.created_by_alias, CASE WHEN a.modified = '0000-00-00 00:00:00' THEN a.created ELSE a.modified END as modified, a.modified_by, uam.name as modified_by_name,CASE WHEN a.publish_up = '0000-00-00 00:00:00' THEN a.created ELSE a.publish_up END as publish_up,a.publish_down, a.images, a.urls, a.attribs, a.metadata, a.metakey, a.metadesc, a.access, a.hits, a.xreference, a.featured, a.language,  LENGTH(a.fulltext) AS readmore,CASE WHEN badcats.id is not null THEN 0 ELSE a.state END AS state,c.title AS category_title, c.path AS category_route, c.access AS category_access, c.alias AS category_alias,CASE WHEN a.created_by_alias > ' ' THEN a.created_by_alias ELSE ua.name END AS author,ua.email AS author_email,parent.title as parent_title, parent.id as parent_id, parent.path as parent_route, parent.alias as parent_alias,ROUND(v.rating_sum / v.rating_count, 0) AS rating, v.rating_count as rating_count,c.published, CASE WHEN badcats.id is null THEN c.published ELSE 0 END AS parents_published FROM ngie_content AS a LEFT JOIN ngie_content_frontpage AS fp ON fp.content_id = a.id LEFT JOIN ngie_categories AS c ON c.id = a.catid LEFT JOIN ngie_users AS ua ON ua.id = a.created_by LEFT JOIN ngie_users AS uam ON uam.id = a.modified_by LEFT JOIN ngie_categories as parent ON parent.id = c.parent_id LEFT JOIN ngie_content_rating AS v ON a.id = v.content_id LEFT OUTER JOIN (SELECT cat.id as id FROM ngie_categories AS cat JOIN ngie_categories AS parent ON cat.lft BETWEEN parent.lft AND parent.rgt WHERE parent.extension = 'com_content' AND parent.published != 1 GROUP BY cat.id ) AS badcats ON badcats.id = c.id WHERE a.access IN (1,1,5) AND c.access IN (1,1,5) AND CASE WHEN badcats.id is null THEN a.state ELSE 0 END = 1 AND (a.publish_up = '0000-00-00 00:00:00' OR a.publish_up <= '2015-04-13 23:49:52') AND (a.publish_down = '0000-00-00 00:00:00' OR a.publish_down >= '2015-04-13 23:49:52') ORDER BY  c.lft,   CASE WHEN a.publish_up = '0000-00-00 00:00:00' THEN a.created ELSE a.publish_up END  DESC ,  a.created;

It means nothing other, than show ALL articles, and i have more than 5.000.

Ok, than it is logically that there running 5.000 of the "SELECT m.tag_id"-queries when the query before ask for all the 5.000 articles.

But the problem is:
I dont find a solution to solve that problem. I dont know why or what produces these "SELECT"-query.

When i look on my "log/"-order, the most times every minute produce a bot (or anything) other a big file with these slow queries. Most time its my "HDsports.at_start1823.sql"-File - thats my frontpage. But only when redirect from a dead-link to frontpage. When i called frontpage (or impressum, or any other page on my site) directly there are not these slow querys.

My suspicion is that, these querys produces a big load on my database and makes my site so slowly.

2. When i save an new article in an category with 1.000 existing article, the time for saving is 2 minutes.
   when i open in the "log/"-order my "HDsports.at_com_contentedit"-sql-File there are lot of these queries:

UPDATE ngie_content SET ordering = 1 WHERE id = '10403';
UPDATE ngie_content SET ordering = 2 WHERE id = '10293';

There is for every existing article id in these category one query, that set the article 1 number higher. The Article with id "10403", that had before 0, goes now to 1. The Article with ID "10293" goes from 1 to 2. And so on.
Is these normal?

I maked a new Joomla-Installation and only imported my articles and categorys (with J2XML), and than i saved again an article in the category with the 1000 existing articles, and the waiting time where also 2 minutes.

So i ask me, why i am the only 1 joomla-user who have these problem? i think many joomla-user have categorys with more than 1.000 articles and i dont found any discussions about these problem...

If anybody will take a look on my file: i have uploaded it on my server:
http://www.hdsports.at/slow-queries.zip

Sorry for my long text. I hope anyone have the time to read that all and maybe can help to solve these problem.

Best regards from Austria, Tom! Now its late, i should go to bed ;)

Comment: Well it sounds like a few things are going on. First you probably have a corrupt assets table for the imported articles. You need to run assetfix or else possibly do something by hand. I don't really understand what you are saying about hte bots but it's possible your 1.5 site was hacked and that they are still trying to come back and do whatever they were doing.

Comment: Hey Elin, i used the AssetFix but without succes, because i get every time a 404-Gateaway Timout. So i found no way to fix the corrupt assets.
I dont know how i can solve that by hand? 

forgott that about the bots. i mean when i go to an false link on my site, than there are running a query that call ALL articles of my site, what makes my site-performance very bad. maybe its also a problem coming from the assets-table, i dont know.

Comment: Ok we will talk tomorrow

Answer (score 0):

Before doing any core optimization, you should make sure that you all your tables are using InnoDB and that [MySQL is optimized for InnoDB databases](http://www.itoctopus.com/mysql-innodb-optimization-for-large-joomla-websites) - there are simple settings changes that you can make in your `my.cnf` file that will make your website fly. If you still have problems, then you should consider having a more power server (make sure that the server has lots of memory and has an SSD drive), if all else fails, then you should go with optimizing the core, but I suspect that it won't have to come to this.